# Typing out react-transition-group handlers in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to type out handlers that are passed to some of the `react-transition-group` components, such as `addEndListener` in `<CSSTransition />`. But I cannot find a way to type it properly and avoid TypeScript errors.

link to a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-transition-group-typescript-q8jkz?file=/src/App.tsx) with the type error.

Eg.:

```
<CSSTransition
  // TypeScript Error on next line: 
    addEndListener={(node: HTMLElement, done: () => void) => {
      node.addEventListener("transitionend", done, false);
    }}
    classNames="fade"
  >
  <div className="button-container">
    <Button onClick={() => setState((state) => !state)}>
      {state ? "Hello, world!" : "Goodbye, world!"}
    </Button>
  </div>
</CSSTransition>
```

Versions of react, react-transition-group and their @types equivalents:

```
"react": "^16.13.1"
"react-transition-group": "^4.4.1"
"@types/react": "^16.9.43"
"@types/react-transition-group": "^4.4.0"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify the generic parameter to [CSSTransition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-transition-group/CSSTransition.d.ts#L43), which decides the type of the callback [based on if that ref is HTMLElement or not](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-transition-group/Transition.d.ts#L10) by using [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html). So in your case (this requires typescript >= 2.9):

```js
<CSSTransition<undefined>
    addEndListener={(node: HTMLElement, done: () => void) => {
      node.addEventListener("transitionend", done, false);
    }}
    classNames="fade"
  >
  <div className="button-container">
    <Button onClick={() => setState((state) => !state)}>
      {state ? "Hello, world!" : "Goodbye, world!"}
    </Button>
  </div>
</CSSTransition>
```